# Javascript WinJS.xhr not updating array contents

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am starting out with developing Win8 App with Javascript. I am new to javascript hence I am not too strong with the language. I am trying to parse a json response in my code and store it in an array. Now I want the array to be of objects with particular properties which I am trying to set in the steps of parsing.
But, it seems that the array is not getting updated within the WinJS.xhr portion. To make it more clear, the REF 1(comment in the code below) console output works fine, but REF 2(comment in the code below) console output throws an error as follows:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'Name' of undefined
>   or null reference

```
var sampleArr = new Array();

WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://some-api-with-json-response" }).then(
       function (response) {
           var name= JSON.parse(response.responseText);
           sampleArr[0] = { Name: name.title };
           console.log("First chance:" + sampleArr[0].Name); //REF 1
           item_number++;
           };

console.log("Second chance:" + sampleArr[0].Name); //REF 2
```

Can anyone tell, where am I going wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the XHR call is being performed in the background and, while this is happening the JavaScript runtime moves on to the next statement - which is `REF2`. And so you are trying to read the results of a request before the request itself has completed.

The solution is to put the code that accesses the result in a function which you pass to another call of the `then` method, like this:

```
var sampleArr = new Array();

WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://some-api-with-json-response" }).then(
       function (response) {
           var name = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
           sampleArr[0] = { Name: name.title };
           console.log("First chance:" + sampleArr[0].Name); //REF 1
           item_number++;

       }).then(function () {
           console.log("Second chance:" + sampleArr[0].Name); //REF 2
       });
```

The function that contains `REF2` won't be executed until the function that contains `REF1` has completed and *that* function won't be executed until the XHR request is completed.

Answer (score 2):

`.then(callback)`, the `callback` function will be executed when the request success.

The code of `REF 2` runs before the `callback` function, at that time, `sampleArr[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Hey, I was trying to follow this walk through http://slickthought.net/post/2012/08/16/Windows-8-and-HTML-Part-5-Fetch-Data-with-WinJS.aspx and was doing accordingly. So you suggest that I write the parsing and array updating steps in a separate callback function??

Comment: @user1740173 Yes, just like what you do in ajax.

Comment: `WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://some-api-with-json-response" }).then(callback);
console.log("Second chance:" + sampleArr[0].Name); //REF 2
function callback(response)
{//content as prev}; `

Still the same error persists :( am I doing this wrong??

Comment: It actually does not matter at all whether your callback function is inline with the .then, or is a separate function, in terms of the order in which the code executes. The point is that the console.log("Second chance:" etc. code needs to be *inside* the callback, otherwise, it will execute as soon as you make the call to WinJS.xhr. The whole purpose of .then and it's companion, .done is to give you a place for code that should only execute once the async call returns.